# Redirect 301 HTACCES

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

How I can redirect page from https://url.pl?page=page to https://url.eu/page.html

I used on other page and this below works

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect 301 /page.html /newpage.html
</IfModule>
```

but when I used once below it doesn`t works

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect 301 /page.html /?page=page
</IfModule>
```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Redirect 301 https://www.domain.eu/page.html  https://www.domain.eu/?page=page
</IfModule>
```

I also used RewriteRule but it also doesn`t works

htacess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]




RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} https://www.maripol.pl/en/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://maripol.pl/en/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index.html$ https://maripol.pl/en [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ https://maripol.pl/en [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*),more.html$ index.php?page=more&id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*),pogodzinach.html$ index.php?page=pogodzinach&id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*),(.*).html$ index.php?page=oferta&id=$1&url=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ ?page=$1 [NC,L]



RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /en/\?page=informacje\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/?$ https://maripol.pl/en/informacje.html? [L,R,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect /?page=page to /page.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /en/\?page=informacje\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/?$ https://maripol.pl/en/informacje.html? [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: Sorry I mean  https://url.pl?page=page to https://url.eu/page.html. When I do RewriteRule /?page=informacje  ^informacje\.html$ [L,R,NE] it doesn`t works.

Comment: It doesn`t work. I need to change from this https://maripol.pl/en/?page=informacje to this https://maripol.pl/en/informacje.html. I was tried RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=3
RewriteRule ^en/informacje\.php$ /en/informacje.html/? [L,R=301] but it also doesn`t work.

Comment: @devil1321 I updated the code as per your comment. Please test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Ok it works when I`m in root at Polish version. I need to chage it for /en directiory

Comment: @devil1321  You can remove the `en/` from the pattern if you want to use it in `/en/` dir. Just change the RewriteRule pattern `^en/?$` to `^$` .

Comment: I tried your solution, but this page says https://www.sureoak.com/seo-tools/301-redirect-checker theurl is not redirected. I have 3 htacces file for every directory. In root directory it works and I have 302 code and says is redirected but in /en don`t

Comment: Ok sorry it work. I thought thath i need to add ^en/?$. Thanks